# Rotation of a part of sprite in XNA

Tags: xna, rotation

I have a texture with 250px width and 2000px height. 250x250 part of it drawn on screen according to various conditions (some kind of sprite sheet, yes). All I want is to draw it within a fixed destination rectangle with some rotation. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.** Here's how to effectively rotate your destination rectangle:

Take a look at the [overloads for `SpriteBatch.Draw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx).

Notice that none of the overloads that take a `Rectangle` as a destination take a rotation parameter. It's because such a thing does not make much sense. It's ambiguous as to how you want the destination rotated.

But you can achieve the same effect as setting a destination rectangle by careful use of the `position` and `scale` parameters. Combine these with the `origin` (centroid of scaling and rotation, specified in pixels in relation to your `sourceRectangle`) and `rotation` parameters to achieve the effect you want.

(If, on the other hand, you want to "fit" to a rectangle - effectively scaling *after* rotating - you would have to also use the `transformMatrix` parameter to [`Begin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433701.aspx).)

---

Now - your question isn't quite clear on this point: But if the effect you are after is more like rotating your *source* rectangle, this is not something you can achieve with plain ol' SpriteBatch.

The quick-and-dirty way to achieve this is to set a viewport that acts as your destination rectangle. Then draw your rotated sprite within it. Note that SpriteBatch's coordinate system is based on the viewport, not the screen.

The "nicer" (but much harder to implement) way to do it would be to not use SpriteBatch at all, but implement your own sprite drawing that will allow you to rotate the texture coordinates.